# How to optimise cell range selection in Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a range of data in a column (500 data points) and I need to analyse them in a table, 250 points at a time. As such, the first time it is A1:A250, and then A2:251, etc. So I have to do this 250 times. Any tips for optimising the retrieving of the data in column A, to then placing it in a new table containing the 250 units.

If I was coding I would just say =A(N+1):A(N+250) where N is the number of times the process has been done previously, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to do it in Excel.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using VBA? Because this is easily doable.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a number of ways.  The simplest one, I think, is to use formulas.

Range `E2` is named `offset`, by changing its value you can show values offset by that number.  There are other ways of doing it as well.  HTH.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be about as easy to create all 251 sets at the one time, say with (in B1 copied across to IR1 and then B1:IR1 copied down to B250):

```
=INDEX(OFFSET($A1,COLUMN()-2,,250,1),1,1)
```

That is quite a lot of calculation when involving a volatile formula so having created all the sets you might want to Copy/Paste Special/Values over the top before any further processing.